# How can I filter data based on the character response of multiple variables?

Tags: r, filter, extract

I am trying to subset (or filter, not sure which is better) my data to get only observations that all had test1 and either test2 or test3.  So even though test2 may have not been performed, as long as test3 was then the id can stay in the dataframe.

I have tried looking for a number of other solutions, but most I have found rely on numeric ranges.  My responses are all characters

```
test1 <- c("Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive")
test2 <- c("NA", "Negative", "NA", "NA", "Negative")
test3 <- c("NA", "Negative", "NA", "Positive", "Negative")
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df<- data.frame(id, test1, test2, test3)
```

```
id    test1      test2      test3
1     Negative   NA         NA
2     Positive   Negative   Negative
3     Negative   NA         NA
4     Negative   NA         Positive
5     Positive   Negative   Negative
```

I would like my results to look like this:

Since the samples with ID 2,4, and 5 all had test1 and at least one of the other tests they remain, since samples with ID 1 and 3 did not have wither test2 or test3 they were excluded.

```
id    test1      test2      test3
2     Positive   Negative   Negative
4     Negative   NA         Positive
5     Positive   Negative   Negative
```

Comment: So you really have the string "NA" in your data? If so, you could do `subset(df, test1!="NA" & (test2 != "NA" | test3!="NA"))` but if you have proper NA values in R, then `subset(df, !is.na(test1) & (!is.na(test2) | !is.na(test3)))` would work. The `|` is for "or"

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfect.